# Why is there blue 1" edges on developed 35mm film?

Tags: troubleshooting, artifacts, 35mm, minolta, color-blue

I have taken some photos on my Minolta XG-1 35mm film camera and 8 of the 24  photos have blue edges. Some have them on just one edge, some on both and some on the other edge. Can anyone tell me what might be causing this? 
I can't check the negatives to see if it's the same.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a possible light leak. What happened to the negs?

Comment: This isn't by chance high ISO film that went through an xray machine, is it? Is there a sharp line in the bleaching on the lefthand side or does it happen to align with a tree trunk?

Answer (score 5):

This is definitely edge-fogged film. We can’t say if the film was light-struck due to improper camera loading /unloading or camera light-leak or if the film was mishandled at the processing lab. All are suspect. Film cameras should be loaded and unloaded in subdued light.

You would be wise to test your camera to see if it is leaking light. Often the light seal at the edges of the hinged back become faulty. To test: Procure a tiny key-chain flashlight, one that stays on when switched. Place this lit flashlight in the film loading area and close the camera. Now retire to a closet or otherwise dark area. Examine the camera from all angles. If you don’t see light right away, stay in this dark place for 15 minutes. It takes that long for your eyes to dark adopt. This test works, if light can leak in, it can also leak out.

Best of luck discovering the cause!